# A function to improve setInterval() prevents an audio file from playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, setinterval

I have written some code that allows an audio file to play and images to pop up in a div element when the user hits the start button. On top of that a blue circle bounces around on a clear canvas on top of the images. I am going to want to be able to "accurately" display an image on top of the last image every 50 milliseconds. Sadly the `setInterval(function, 50)` is fairly inaccurate and I have tried to improve it by writing my own script:

```
function interval(var f, var w){

    var start = (new Date).getTime();
    var func = f;
    var times = t;
    while(on){
        while(true){
            if(w <=(((new Date).getTime()) - start)){
                func();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without this script in my code the program works fine but inaccurately. When I add the code the audio file doesn't play and the images don't loop, even if I leave the setIntervals and don't call the interval method. When I run this it displays `Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not definedonclick @ dreamFlashes.html:138` to the console. All ideas on **how to get the audio file playing and the images looping while the interval function replaces the setInervals function** would be very helpful! Thank you for your time and help!

Here is the working code but without the interval method:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>flashing page</title>

<style>
#imgZone{
 position: fixed;
z-index:1;
height:500px;
width:600px;
top: 50px;
left:300px;
}

#myCanvas{
 position: fixed;
 z-index:500000;
 left:300px;
 top:50px;
}

#bt{
position:fixed;
left:45%;
top:600px;
}


</style>

<script>
 var i = 0;
 var p = 0;
 first = 0;
 var rounds;
 imgArray = ["http://files.sharenator.com/finger_monkey07-s400x266-235097.jpg", "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqbBlJBsnTumbHkaKpYiA4GQjPvnyL9DLpeBuRGgJhKSqtEOhxhA", "http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2014/Animals___Monkeys_____The_little_monkey_sitting_on_a_branch_075382_.jpg", "http://www.factrange.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/finger-monkey-factrange.jpg", "http://i0.wp.com/www.thisblogrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/finger-monkey-11.jpg", "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjwea3xDfNQtEPTr8lk6EVNdGWYi5IIZYHmwddhupPqq9YnD8GLw"]
function imageInZone(){
    document.getElementById("imgZone").src = imgArray[i];
    i++;
    p++;
    if(i == imgArray.length){
        i=0;
    }

    if(p >= imgArray.length*2){
        clearInterval(rounds);
    }
    
    
}



 function start(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
       if(first == 0){
            setTimeout(startImages, 5000);
       }
       else{
            rounds = setInterval(imageInZone, 1000);
       }
       

}



function stop(){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.pause();
       clearInterval(rounds);
}

function startImages(){
       first = 1;
       rounds = setInterval(imageInZone, 1000);
}
</script>

</head>


<script>
var context;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=5;
var dy=5;

function init()
{
  context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(draw,20);
}

function draw()
{
  context.clearRect(0,0, 600,500);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
  // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
  context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  // Boundary Logic
if( x<0 || x>600) dx=-dx; 
if( y<0 || y>500) dy=-dy; 
x+=dx; 
y+=dy;
}

</script>


<body onLoad="init();">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500" >
  </canvas>


<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3" ></audio>
<div id = "bt">
<input type="button" value="START"  onclick="start()"/>
<input type="button" value="STOP"  onclick="stop()"/>
</div>
<div id = "flashZone">
<img id = "imgZone" src = ""/>
</div>
<div 




</body>

</html>
```

Here is the nonfunctional code with the interval method:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>flashing page</title>

<style>
#imgZone{
 position: fixed;
z-index:1;
height:500px;
width:600px;
top: 50px;
left:300px;
}

#myCanvas{
 position: fixed;
 z-index:500000;
 left:300px;
 top:50px;
}

#bt{
position:fixed;
left:45%;
top:600px;
}


</style>

<script>
 var i = 0;
 var p = 0;
 first = 0;
 var rounds;
 var on = true;
 imgArray = ["http://files.sharenator.com/finger_monkey07-s400x266-235097.jpg", "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqbBlJBsnTumbHkaKpYiA4GQjPvnyL9DLpeBuRGgJhKSqtEOhxhA", "http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2014/Animals___Monkeys_____The_little_monkey_sitting_on_a_branch_075382_.jpg", "http://www.factrange.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/finger-monkey-factrange.jpg", "http://i0.wp.com/www.thisblogrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/finger-monkey-11.jpg", "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjwea3xDfNQtEPTr8lk6EVNdGWYi5IIZYHmwddhupPqq9YnD8GLw"]
function imageInZone(){
    document.getElementById("imgZone").src = imgArray[i];
    i++;
    p++;
    if(i == imgArray.length){
        i=0;
    }

    if(p >= imgArray.length*2){
        on = false;
    }
    
    
}

function interval(var f, var w){

    var start = (new Date).getTime();
    var func = f;
    var times = t;
    while(on){
        while(true){
            if(w <=(((new Date).getTime()) - start)){
                func();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


 function start(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
       if(first == 0){
            setTimeout(startImages, 5000);
       }
       else{
            interval(imageInZone, 1000);
       }
       

}



function stop(){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.pause();
       clearInterval(rounds);
}

function startImages(){
       first = 1;
       intervals(imageInZone, 1000);
}
</script>

</head>


<script>
var context;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=5;
var dy=5;

function init()
{
  context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(draw,20);
}

function draw()
{
  context.clearRect(0,0, 600,500);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
  // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
  context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  // Boundary Logic
if( x<0 || x>600) dx=-dx; 
if( y<0 || y>500) dy=-dy; 
x+=dx; 
y+=dy;
}

</script>


<body onLoad="init();">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500" >
  </canvas>


<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3" ></audio>
<div id = "bt">
<input type="button" value="START"  onclick="start()"/>
<input type="button" value="STOP"  onclick="stop()"/>
</div>
<div id = "flashZone">
<img id = "imgZone" src = ""/>
</div>
<div 




</body>

</html>
```

edit:
I've just tried to use a settimeout and it still doesn't work

```
function playSound() {
  setInterval(function () {
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }, number.value * 1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('spin').classList.remove('spinAnim');
    document.getElementById('number').value = 0;
    audio.stop();
  }, duration.value * 1000);
}
```

Comment: [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: "improve" setInterval? me thinks not. you NEED a timeout in there, even if just 1ms and while'ing the next 49. think of it like the old "doevents" in VB6; let go of the conch so others can perform work.